# Having different font sizes in a sentence

Tags: html, css

How do I have a bigger font size for only a single character in a sentence?

For a example: All characters except `-` in "Click - sign" should be font size 13. And only `-` should be font size 55. The sentence should look normal.
See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLvtjwcw/). The `-` sign is higher than the rest of the text.

```
<div class="aa"> 
    Click <span Style="font-size:30px; line-height:45px;">-</span> sign
</div>
```

```css
aa {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem with the above code?

Comment: @Beki the mis-alignment is just a side-effect of the different font-sizes and related line heights.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: :) thanks. Is there a way to fix the alignment?

Comment: Nice effort with the images Beki. It's good to see a clear explanation of an issue every once in a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use `position: relative;` for hyphen:

```
span {font-size:30px; position: relative; top: 3px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLvtjwcw/1/

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
* { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    font-size: 13px;
}
p span.hlt_txt{
    font-size: 55px; 
    line-height: 0;     
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="aa"> 
    Click <span class="hlt_txt">-</span> sign
</p>
```